# VBA Excel Double If

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have various dropdown menus in the document and need to create a double conditional statement.

So I am trying to do the following:

```
If Cell B14 = Option 1 Then unhide Cells B16:B17
If Cells B17 = Yes Then hide Cells B19:B53
If Cells B17 = No Then show Cells B19:B34
```

So if someone picks `Option 1` from the dropdown menu then there is another drop down menu that appear and if they select `Yes` from the second on it hide the required cells and if they pick `No` it unhides the required cells.

Options 2 & 3 in the first dropdown menu do not need to show the second drop down box.

I have it all working apart from the double if.

Current code is:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$14" Then

    If Range("B14") = "Option 1: Travel Home" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("16:35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Rows("36:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B14") = "Option 2: Travel to next city" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("15").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Rows("16:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows("19:35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows("36").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Rows("37:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B14") = "Option 3: Make own arrangements" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("15:36").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows("39:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End If
```

Option 2 and 3 are working OK just option 1 isn't working to unhide/hide whats necessary and also then need to do the second dropdown option which the alters what is shown.

Comment: Would it be better to use dynamic validation to achieve this?

Comment: You can't hide individual cells. Do you want to hide the entire row?

Comment: Maybe no need for any `IF`. Assuming you want entire rows hidden: `Range("B19:B53").EntireRow.Hidden = Range("B17").Value = "Yes" ` and 
`Range("B19:B34").EntireRow.Hidden = Not(Range("B17").Value = "No")`

Comment: New to this forum.  How do I post my current code? Its over character by 338!

Comment: Put it in the original post using edit.

Comment: apologies this is probably really basic stuff!

Comment: Is `B17` a drop-down choice after the user would select the option in `B14`?

Comment: No problem, we all started somewhere not too far from there - see the **[edit]** link under the tags? (or, well, right here in this comment). Also make sure you read the [**editing help**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), as code blocks need 4 leading spaces to be recognized as such.

Comment: B14 & B17 are both drop down menus. B17 only needs to appear if Option one is selected in B14. It doesn't appear for option 2/3 at the minute which is right. So the idea is cells B16:B35 only appear if the user selects NO to the second drop down which appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the below code and it appears to be behaving as you desire. I did make some seemingly significant changes to the structure, but I did so in hopes of making it both easier to read and maintain going forward. I think my edits are self-explanatory.

I also took the liberty to assume this is a `Worksheet_Change` event even though you did not explicity state as such.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Target.Address

    Case Is = "$B$14"

        Select Case Right(Left(Target.Value, 8), 1)

            Case Is = 1 'Option 1

                Me.Rows("16:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False

            Case Is = 2 'Option 2

                Me.Rows("15").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Me.Rows("16:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Me.Rows("19:35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Me.Rows("36").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Me.Rows("37:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True

            Case Is = 3 'Option 3

                Me.Rows("15:36").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Me.Rows("39:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False

            Case Else 

                Me.Rows("15:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        End Select


    Case Is = "$B$17"

        Me.Range("B19:B35").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (Target.Value = "No")

End Select

End Sub
```

Here's the code to make sure all rows are hidden when the workbook is opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With Me.Worksheets("SheetName") ' change as needed
    .Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    .Rows("15:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic Scott thank you.  Only issue is when I open the document the options which appear if second dropdown is a 'NO' have appeared already and if I select Option 1 in the first drop down it already loads with the 'YES' option to the second and the following questions?

Comment: Basically I would like it so when I open the document all the extra questions are hidden and it only shows til Row 14 (with everything else hidden).  If Option 2 or 3 are selected then these work ok.  If option 1 is selected it then only shows cells B16 & B17 extra and only unhides the following questions if NO is selected in B17?

Comment: @AdamMcClelland - Are you stating how you would *like* it to behave in the last sentence (about Option 1) in your last comment?

Comment: Yes.  So when opened only cells B4:B14 appear. If Option 1 is selected only cells B16&B17 (second drop down) appear and then cells B19:B35 will appear if NO is selected from second drop down.  If option 2 is selected only B4:B15 and B36 appear.  If option 3 is selected B4:B14 and B37:B53 will appear.

Comment: When all drop downs are blank (using empty cell in validation) cells B35:B53 still appear? Also as the dropdown is blank for B17 (again using blank cell in validation) it shows cells B19:B53. If I select No from B17 it shows B37:B53 which shouldn't show?

Comment: @AdamMcClelland - i made another edit. if you need all these test cases that you are giving you should state such up front. I have given you a very solid shell. You can easily debug and edit for any more test cases that come up. If not, please post another question and we are happy to serve in that way.